# Koin Scope and Interface

Tags: android, koin

I am using [**Koin**](https://insert-koin.io/) di library in my project. Version of lib is **1.0.0-RC-1**.

My **module**:

```
val appModule = module {
    scope("UserScope") { UserToaster(androidContext()) as Toaster }
    scope("AnonScope") { AnonToaster(androidContext()) as Toaster }
}
```

I started koin in my **Application** class and created **scope**:

```
override fun onCreate() {
    super.onCreate()

    startKoin(this, listOf(appModule))
    getKoin().getOrCreateScope("AnonScope")
}
```

And next I tried to inject implementation of **Toaster** from current scope to variable in Activity. Here the code:

```
private val toaster: Toaster by inject(scope = "AnonScope")
```

After this I got an error:

```
Caused by: org.koin.error.DependencyResolutionException: Multiple definitions found for type 'interface com.example.nkirilov.playground.Toaster (Kotlin reflection is not available)' - Koin can't choose between :
    Scope [name='UserScope',class='com.example.nkirilov.playground.Toaster']
    Scope [name='AnonScope',class='com.example.nkirilov.playground.Toaster']
    Check your modules definition, use inner modules visibility or definition names.
```

I do not understand why this does not work (If use **single** with different names - it will work). Is that koin bug? How to avoid this error?

Answer (score 2):

I implemented it like this

**Module**:

```
val navigationModule = module {
    scope(DI.APP_SCOPE) { ClassA().create }
    scope(DI.APP_SCOPE) { get(scopeId = DI.APP_SCOPE).classB }
    scope(DI.APP_SCOPE) { get(scopeId = DI.APP_SCOPE).classC }
}

val authModule = module {
    scope(DI.AUTH_SCOPE) { ClassA.create(ChildClassB(get(scopeId = DI.APP_SCOPE))) }
    scope(DI.AUTH_SCOPE) { get(scopeId = DI.AUTH_SCOPE).classB }
    scope(DI.AUTH_SCOPE) { get(scopeId = DI.AUTH_SCOPE).classC }
}
```

**Main Activity**:

```
private val classC: ClassC by inject(scope = getKoin().getOrCreateScope(APP_SCOPE))
```

**AuthActivity**:

```
private val classC: ClassC by inject(scope = getKoin().getOrCreateScope(DI.AUTH_SCOPE))
```

Answer (score 0):

your definitions have the same name in Koin. Current version (~1.0.*) avoid you to specify which scope to use, by automating resolving a type and it's session id.

Can you avoid describe your definitions with same type, like:

```
val appModule = module {
    scope("UserScope") { UserToaster(androidContext()) }
    scope("AnonScope") { AnonToaster(androidContext()) }
}
```

Else we would need a feature to specify which scope to use when resolving a type. You would resolve it with:

```
val userScope = getScope("UserScope")
get<Toaster>(scope = userScope)
```

Comment: It did not work for me. I created a sample project on Github, if you will be free, check it, please. [Here link:] (https://github.com/KolinLoures/TestScopeKoin). TIA

Comment: let me check that 

Comment: edited my comment. Can you use directly your types for now?

Comment: Unfortunately, i can't. In my work project, I need to set implementation in according what scope had created. May be, Is there another approach to realize this idea?

Comment: May be use this: 
getKoin().get<Toaster>(
                clazz = Toaster::class,
                filter = { a: BeanDefinition<*> -> a.attributes["scope"] == currentScope.id }
            )

Comment: a bit hard to find it like that, but the main thing is that visibility is not restraint against with the scope. You can raise an issue on github.

Comment: @ArnaudGiuliani Could you please check [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/73235897/813951)? We need an authoritative reference.

Comment: This is a bit outdated, this question address Koin 1.x. In Koin 3.x, you can retrieve a scope with koin.getScope( /* scopeId */ )
On the Scope object, you can resolve your dependency with get() or inject().

Check the online documentation: https://insert-koin.io/docs/reference/koin-core/scopes#scope-id--scope-name